# Expected Primary-Expression before ']' token?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to be able to call a function with the vector and for some reason it's saying "expected primary expression before ']'. The vector could hold any number of files, depending on the amount of numbers in myfile, so I'm not sure what I should put there.

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; // not recommended

double averageCalc(string[],int);

int main () {
    double average;
    string line;
    ifstream myfile ("array_pgmdata.txt");
    //int index = 0;            // not needed
    //string myArray[index];    // UB - if it even compiles, it's a VLA of size 0.

    std::vector<std::string> myArray;    // use this instead to be able to grow it
                                         // dynamically

    if (myfile)                          // open and in a good state
    {
        // while (! myfile.eof() )       // It'll not be eof when you've read the last line
                                         // only when you try to read beynd the last line,
                                         // so you'll add "line" one extra time at the end
                                         // if you use that. Use this instead:
        while(getline(myfile, line))
        {
            // myArray[index++] << line; // you have 0 elements in the array and
                                         // can't add to it in any way
            myArray.push_back(line);
        }
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

    for(size_t idx=0; idx < myArray.size(); ++idx) {
        std::cout << myArray[idx] << "\n";
    }


    average = averageCalc(myArray[], line); // error here

    return 0;
}

double averageCalc(string nums[], int count)
{
    int a, total, elements, averaged1, averaged2;
//  string averaged2;
    for(a = 0; a < count; a++)
    {
        total+=a;
        elements++;
    }
    averaged1 = total / elements;

    return averaged2;
}
```

Comment: `myArray` is a vector, but your function expects an array. Is this a typo?

Comment: `std::vector<std::string> myArray;`  -- Why isn't your function declared as taking a `std::vector<std::string>` (or reference to one), if that is what you're sending to it?  It's simple -- if your type is `T`, then declare your function to take a `T` or reference to `T`.  It doesn't matter how "complex" the `T` seems to be.

Comment: @chrisMM Probably! I had it as an array at first and didn't know i needed to change it

Answer (score 0):

There's a few problems here. Firstly, your function `averageCalc` expects a parameter of type `string[]` which is an array of strings. When you call the function, you are trying to pass it a `std::vector<string>`, which is not an array of strings, it is a class. Presumably, you would want to change your function to take in a vector, like so:

```
double averageCalc( const std::vector<string> & nums ); // no need for size now
```

The other issue you have is in calling your function. When you call it, you pass `myArray[]` as a parameter, which is the error you compiler is giving you. This is not valid syntax, you simply want to pass in `myArray`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the error occurs becase firstly you create the array with `std::vector<std::string> myArray;` so the data is string type but when you want to calculate the average value the function expects a value int, double etc. in order to perform math. Either change the string to int or use a function to convert it:

```
int main() 
{
    string s = "12345"; 

    // object from the class stringstream 
    stringstream geek(s); 

    // The object has the value 12345 and stream 
    // it to the integer x 
    int x = 0; 
    geek >> x; 

    // Now the variable x holds the value 12345 
    cout << "Value of x : " << x; 

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: So to switch the data type do I just replace all 'string' words to 'int'?

Comment: The calculation must happen in int or double, however if you want to type worlds you need to use the function i send in order to make it int and words can be calculated